# Array.map returning cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to access and display "teams" in this array, however when I try to map it out to display the data I get the error: "cannot read property 'Map' of undefined. Whenever I display other portions of the array, it works fine. I am just having issues with the "teams" array within the array. Any help is appreciated<3 thanks.

Here is my array of data:

```
{
    "gameId": 3226262256,
    "platformId": "NA1",
    "gameCreation": 1575583791449,
    "gameDuration": 1526,
    "queueId": 400,
    "mapId": 11,
    "seasonId": 13,
    "gameVersion": "9.23.299.3089",
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "teams": [
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "win": "Fail",
            "firstBlood": true,
            "firstTower": false,
            "firstInhibitor": false,
            "firstBaron": false,
            "firstDragon": false,
            "firstRiftHerald": false,
            "towerKills": 1,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "baronKills": 0,
            "dragonKills": 2,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 0,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 111,
                    "pickTurn": 1
                },
                {
                    "championId": 25,
                    "pickTurn": 2
                },
                {
                    "championId": 24,
                    "pickTurn": 3
                },
                {
                    "championId": 235,
                    "pickTurn": 4
                },
                {
                    "championId": 238,
                    "pickTurn": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "win": "Win",
            "firstBlood": false,
            "firstTower": true,
            "firstInhibitor": true,
            "firstBaron": true,
            "firstDragon": true,
            "firstRiftHerald": true,
            "towerKills": 9,
            "inhibitorKills": 2,
            "baronKills": 1,
            "dragonKills": 1,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 1,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 266,
                    "pickTurn": 6
                },
                {
                    "championId": 89,
                    "pickTurn": 7
                },
                {
                    "championId": 64,
                    "pickTurn": 8
                },
                {
                    "championId": -1,
                    "pickTurn": 9
                },
                {
                    "championId": 141,
                    "pickTurn": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

And my code I am trying to map it out in:

```
import React from 'react';
import './MatchHistory.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const MatchData = ({ datas }) => {
console.log('data: ' + datas);
  return (
        <div>    
            <Card>
              <h5 className="card-title">Full Match data test Pull...</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Lane:{datas.platformId}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title">MapId:{datas.mapId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Mode: {datas.gameMode}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Duration: {datas.gameDuration}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">SeasonId: {datas.seasonId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Version: {datas.gameVersion}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Type: {datas.gameType}</h5>
               {datas.teams.map(data => (            
               <h5 className="card-title">Type: {data.teamId}</h5>))}
              <h5 className="card-title">Participant info: champ, KDA, etc</h5>
            </Card>  
      </div> 
   )
}

      export default MatchData;
```

Comment: Is it right to use `{data.teams.teamId}` ?? I think It should be `{data.teamId}`

Comment: here `teams` is itself an array, so you have to ittirate it or just use as an example teams[0].platformId

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{datas.teams && datas.teams.map(({teamId})=> (            
  <h5 className="card-title" key={teamId}>Type: {teamId}</h5>))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the team id of the first team by using something like this

```
data["teams"][0]["teamId"]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting/syntax was slightly off. Try

```
{datas.teams.map(data => <h5 className="card-title">Type: {data.teamId}</h5>)}
```

or

```
{datas.teams.map(data => {
     return <h5 className="card-title">Type: {data.teamId}</h5>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here,

```
{data.teams.teamId}
```

You don't have `teams` object. You should be doing this,

```
{data.teamId}
```

For the extra care, you can do this,

```
{datas.teams && datas.teams.length && datas.teams.map(data => (            
    <h5 className="card-title">Type: {data.teamId}</h5>)
)}
```

Comment: even when i take out teams, its still giving me the same error

Comment: @FaithElliott Did you add `datas.teams && datas.teams.length` to check?

Comment: ooh that second portion worked!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The map function only applicable for Array. If the array is in this format then you can apply map operation like this to get the teams.

```js
let sampleArray = [{
    "gameId": 3226262256,
    "platformId": "NA1",
    "gameCreation": 1575583791449,
    "gameDuration": 1526,
    "queueId": 400,
    "mapId": 11,
    "seasonId": 13,
    "gameVersion": "9.23.299.3089",
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "teams": [
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "win": "Fail",
            "firstBlood": true,
            "firstTower": false,
            "firstInhibitor": false,
            "firstBaron": false,
            "firstDragon": false,
            "firstRiftHerald": false,
            "towerKills": 1,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "baronKills": 0,
            "dragonKills": 2,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 0,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 111,
                    "pickTurn": 1
                },
                {
                    "championId": 25,
                    "pickTurn": 2
                },
                {
                    "championId": 24,
                    "pickTurn": 3
                },
                {
                    "championId": 235,
                    "pickTurn": 4
                },
                {
                    "championId": 238,
                    "pickTurn": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "win": "Win",
            "firstBlood": false,
            "firstTower": true,
            "firstInhibitor": true,
            "firstBaron": true,
            "firstDragon": true,
            "firstRiftHerald": true,
            "towerKills": 9,
            "inhibitorKills": 2,
            "baronKills": 1,
            "dragonKills": 1,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 1,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 266,
                    "pickTurn": 6
                },
                {
                    "championId": 89,
                    "pickTurn": 7
                },
                {
                    "championId": 64,
                    "pickTurn": 8
                },
                {
                    "championId": -1,
                    "pickTurn": 9
                },
                {
                    "championId": 141,
                    "pickTurn": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}];
    let teamArray = sampleArray.map(ele =>                            ele.teams)[0];
  console.log(teamArray);
```